# Scala/Java compilation order in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Is there any equivalent of `compileOrder := CompileOrder.JavaThenScala` for Intellij(14) scala plugin? I use Lombok and project doesnt compile with "Make Project".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `Compile Order: Java then Scala` setting under the path

> `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Scala Compiler`

Comment: It didn't solve my problem with lombok, but it is a direct answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: I just did a quick search what Lombok is. And I suppose you also need to configure `Compiler` `Annotation processors` settings.

Comment: Thank! This was crucial. Now everything compiles fine.